# How can I emphasis the importance of individual items in an unordered list

Tags: html, semantics, schema.org, microformats

I would like to use semantic mark-up to emphasise each items importance or priority.

Here is an example of what i mean.

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
  <h2 itemprop="name">Wish List</h2><br>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement">Google glass</li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement">Galaxy S4</li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement">MacBook Pro</li>
</ul>
```

I was contemplating using heading tags but I am not sure if this is the correct use. e.g

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement"><h6>Least Important</h6></li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement"><h1>Most Important</h1></li>
</ul>
```

I'm just looking for a little advice on whether there is a CORRECT way of doing this? possibly microdata, microformats or RDFa?

Comment: The question does not define what it means by “semantic mark-up” (a common buzzword with very vague semantics) and what it is assumed to achieve. The first code example is invalid markup, and the second one is illogical (headings with no content that they would be headers for), so it is really not possible to infer what the goal might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn’t use headings that way. Heading content is important, yes, but that doesn’t mean that important content should be a heading. Your first example is invalid (a list may only contain `li` elements), your second example messes with the document outline.

The [`strong` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) represents "strong importance for its contents". You increase the importance by using several `strong` elements for the same content:

> The relative level of importance of a piece of content is given by its number of ancestor `strong` elements; each `strong` element increases the importance of its contents.

The HTML5 spec also has an example for such usage:

```
<p>
  <strong>Warning.</strong> This dungeon is dangerous.
  <strong>Avoid the ducks.</strong> Take any gold you find.
  <strong><strong>Do not take any of the diamonds</strong>,
  they are explosive and <strong>will destroy anything within
  ten meters.</strong></strong> You have been warned.
</p>
```

(note that `<strong>Do not take any of the diamonds</strong>` is nested in another `strong` element)

So this is the correct way in HTML5.

Regarding your example: If you have a wishlist that is sorted from least to most important (or the other way around), you should use `ol` rather than `ul`, as the order is meaningful and important. So your wishlist could look like:

```
<ol reversed>
  <li><!-- least important item --></li> 
  <li><!-- another not-soo-very important one --></li>
  <li><strong><!-- important --></strong></li>
  <li><strong><!-- more important than the previous one, but not that much of a difference --></strong></li>
  <li><strong><strong><!-- most important item --></strong></strong></li> 
</ol>
```

(If it’s not sorted in this way, go with `ul` and use the `strong` elements accordingly.)

---

Now, you could enhance this with RDFa or Microdata, of course. Therefore you’d need an appropriate vocabulary. I don’t know any. Maybe you could make use of some sort of rating vocabulary? You could give each item a score/rating, like how much you want to have it.

Theoretical example in Turtle:

```
myWishlistItems:1 ex:hasImportance 0.9
myWishlistItems:2 ex:hasImportance 0.85
myWishlistItems:3 ex:hasImportance 0.7
myWishlistItems:4 ex:hasImportance 0.7
myWishlistItems:5 ex:hasImportance 0.7
myWishlistItems:6 ex:hasImportance 0.2
```

---

Alternative: state the semantics in the content, e.g. group the levels of importance.

You could use a `dl`, e.g.:

```
<section>
  <h1>My wishlist</h1>

  <dl>
    <dt>MUST HAVE!</dt>
      <dd>…</dd>
      <dd>…</dd>
    <dt>Would be very cool</dt>
      <dd>…</dd>
      <dd>…</dd>
    <dt>I like that, sometimes</dt>
      <dd>…</dd>
      <dd>…</dd>
  </dl>

</section>
```

or an `ol` with `section` elements, so you can use grouping headings, e.g.:

```
<section>
  <h1>My wishlist</h1>

  <ol>

    <li>
      <section>
        <h2>MUST HAVE!</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>…</li>
          <li>…</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </li>

    <li>
      <section>
        <h2>Would be very cool</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>…</li>
          <li>…</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </li>

    <li>
      <section>
        <h2>I like that, sometimes</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>…</li>
          <li>…</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </li>

  </ol>

</section>
```

Comment: Avoid complicated contents in `<li>`. Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213214/is-it-a-good-practice-to-put-articles-inside-lis#answer-16299980).

Comment: @IanY.: I don’t agree with [Richard](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-wai-ig/2013AprJun/0176.html) in this case. Example: Think of a search engine result page. Each result would be an `article` and might contain the title, a snippet, a photo, additional links etc. And all these results (→ `article`s) should be in a `ol` (sorted by rank). This example would even be more complex than the wishlist. – However, I don’t think that you’d *have* to use a list in my last wishlist example, but I wouldn’t say that it should be avoided.

Comment: I had [posted](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-wai-ig/2013AprJun/0236.html) the idea regarding search result page. And [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-wai-ig/2013AprJun/0237.html) is the reply.

Comment: @IanY.: Again, I don’t agree with him. `article` is not only for full-texts. However, this is beside the point: You’d still want to use a sectioning element. So if Richard doesn’t want to use `article`, he might use `section` (or even no sectioning element at all, which I would advise against) → but this doesn’t change the complexity argument he made before. The content would still be complex (title+abstract+photo+tags+author+date+…), no matter which element you use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a scale with several levels of priority, there's no way to do that in html.  Using headings would clutter the [outline](http://html5doctor.com/outlines/), in a way that's clearly "un-semantic". It's likely not worth trying to express in RDF either.  What would consume it?  Perhaps you have more details in mind, that would shed more light on this...

Since there's no way to express it in HTML elements or attributes, the data would not be accessible to all readers.  You know how to style items with a spectrum of colors, but screen-readers wouldn't read those colors aloud.

You might simplify this to an ordered list - items in order of priority.  Or two levels of importance, where a few critical items are highlighted using `<strong>`.

(If you take the HTML5 spec *literally*, you can nest `<strong>` multiple times for higher levels of priority.  But it's unlikely to be supported for your use case.  Not in current screen-readers, and not in the browser default stylesheet.  So I wouldn't consider this a legitimate use).