# Semantic HTML of an articles list

Tags: html, semantic-markup

In a typical index of articles (like a blog without excerpt) like this image:

[image: example]

those items should be a list (`<ul><li>`) or just divs?

And also, they should be figure/figcaption? Because would make some sense, but also... picture is part of an artcile not the main content, so maybe title/description is not the caption of the image, but the caption of the article.

what do you think?

EDIT: a live example - https://news.google.com/?hl=en

Comment: I think that semantic mark-up depends on the content. And you haven't provided any.

Comment: Like most questions about “semantic HTML”, this a matter of opinions and interpretations of vague statements in draft specifications.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I’d use an `article` for each snippet (i.e. a news teaser).

Each `article` contains an `h1` element for the heading, an `img` element for the image, and `p` element(s) for the text.

As you probably want to link to a full version, you could enclose all elements in one `a` element (which is allowed in HTML5), or the heading etc. only.

So it could look like:

```
<article>
  <h1><a href="" title=""><!-- news title --></a></h1>
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <p><!-- news description --></p>
</article>
```

Only use `figure` if this image itself should have a separate caption. The news description (here contained in `p`) usually isn’t the caption for that image.

You may change the order of the `article` children. Thanks to the way sectioning elements work, the heading doesn’t have to be the first element.

You may use an `ul`, but it’s not necessary. `ol`, however, should only be used if the order is really meaningful for understanding the content (i.e. a different order would change the meaning of the document). Typical example: if the items are ranked by relevance (e.g. most relevant teaser at the top), you should use `ol`.

---

Regarding [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307443/semantic-html-of-an-articles-list/19317918#comment28595841_19307814) if the teaser should be an `article`:

Don’t confuse `article` (HTML5 element) with the term "article" (English language). `article` has a separate [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-article-element) that doesn’t necessarily have something to do with the understanding of the term "article".

The teaser should also be an `article` – the teaser `article` and the fulltext `article` are *different* `article`s, although they refer to the same entity.

Comment: You should actually use `li` for accessibility. When you enter an `ul`, a screen reader will inform the user of how many items there are in the list, thus facilitating navigation and the overall user experience.

Comment: How does this compare to using another semantic tag like `section` as a container for `article` tags?

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy: You’d typically use a `section` (or sometimes `aside` instead) that groups all these `article` elements, yes.

Comment: @unor: so it's contained in `<article>` because it is a teaser article (with article summary/description)? If we remove the article summary/description, would it still be wrapped in `<article>`?

Comment: @deathlock: What would be left then, only the title+link? In that case I’d not use `article` (or another sectioning content element), but just a `ul`.

Comment: Yes, only title+image+link. `ul` would be more fitting then?

Comment: @deathlock: In my opinion, yes, a list (without sectioning content elements) would be more appropriate in such a case. It’s subjective at which point exactly an `article` is warranted, though.

Comment: is it allowed to have multiple tags `<h1>` on a page?

Comment: @アレックス: See [this answer on Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/274668/63183).

Answer (score 13):

The answers here leave a lot to be desired. The HTML spec has an example of blog post markup with comments inside.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-article-element

While the accepted answer has copy/pasted the description of how the `<article>` element is used it does not answer the question asked at all.

Here is the answer from W3.ORG

> If you can use a native HTML element [HTML51] or attribute with the
>   semantics and behavior you require already built in, instead of
>   re-purposing an element and adding an ARIA role, state or property to
>   make it accessible, then do so.

Here is the logic I am proceeding with after researching:
I have a list of reviews. 
Each review is ordered by helpful votes. 
Therefore the first level will be an ordered list since reviews will be ordered by their helpful votes. Otherwise an unordered list would suffice such as the nested comments:

```
<ol>
    <li class="review" role="article"> <!-- reviews ordered by votes-->
        <header>
            <h2>Review title</h2>
        </header>
        <p>Review body</p>
        <section class="comments">
            <ul>
                <li class="comment" role="article"> <!-- comments with votes-->

                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </li>
</ol>
```

[An insightful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16299980/1440240) by @Terrill Thompson explains that screen readers are helped by semantic list markup. So yes, a list of `<article>`'s does make sense. As things become complex he mentions how confusing it can be. This is where ARIA, `role` and `tabindex` attributes should absolutely be added and tested.

That answer has a comment directing users to a conversation at [W3.ORG](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-wai-ig/2013AprJun/0176.html). By definition it appears that `<article>` would not be part of a list where it should be "stand alone content". However the question here, myself and probably you reading this require a deeper answer where `article` applies to a true list of articles.

Such as:

- List of blog articles with excerpts
- Search results
- Reviews
- Comments

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinion question so it comes down to preference. 
Based on your image, I would use a `<ul> <li>` though I could get the same result using divs.

Comment: I wonder if `<ol>` would be more correct, since people usually visualize blog posts ordered chronologically (or reversed).

Answer (score 1):

If each item represents an article, then each should be represented using [`<article>` elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-article-element).

If you feel that it's an ordered or unordered list of articles, then you could use `<ol>` or `<ul>` elements respectively.

I would recommend keeping the markup as simple as possible and as complex as necessary, so something along the lines of:

```
<div>
  <article>
    <img>
    <div>…</div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img>
    <div>…</div>
  </article>
  …
</div>
```

Comment: but even if each item represents an article, is not an article at all, just a link to the article, dont?

Comment: IMHO, the semantic meaning of `article` is something along the lines of 'a separate entry of content'. Akin to `aside`, but where `aside` merely refers to content separate from the main content, `article` refers to content that is not only separate from the main content, but is actually its own article in the sense that it has its own page with its own URL. And I think that here, that is clearly the case. That is why I would use `article` here.

Answer (score 0):

As other people said, I think that each article should be marked with an `article` tag.

I also suggest to surround the whole list with an `aside` tag. So If you have one main article in the page (surrounded with `main`), it will not be affected by the other articles.

Here is a [nice article](http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/) about `aside`.

Answer (score 0):

Throughout my career, I've encountered this situation numerous times and have experimented with various iterations of the presented approach. I strongly believe that the method I'm suggesting is the most semantic and user-friendly way to create fully clickable articles.

Open to suggestions!

```css
* {margin:0;}

.article {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.article img { width: 100%; vertical-align: bottom; }
.article-content { padding: 10px; display:flex;flex-direction:column;gap:12px; }

.u-fill-space {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
  <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/238/536/354.jpg?hmac=lTwb8DbxMAh_q5cLhPzEQP7gbKMA4MAythQrpcQSm3U" alt="image description" />
  <div class="article-content">
    <h1>Article Title</h1>
    <p>Article description...</p>
    <a class="u-fill-space" href="https://example.com">
      <span class="sr-only">Read Article</span>
    </a>
    <!-- Optional Visual Button -->
    <span aria-hidden="true">Read Article</span>
  </div>
</article>
```