# Semantic: should the image in an article list wrapped in figure?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

In typical index of articles (like a blog, news portal), such as this:

[image]

Should it have the image thumbnail contained in `figure`, or letting it alone would be fine?

[The HTML5 spec defines `figure` as](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/figure.html),

> The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a
>   caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a
>   single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved
>   away from the main flow of the document without affecting the
>   document’s meaning.

But I'm still having problems grasping if it means we should/should not put the image thumbnail inside a `figure`.

For example, even without the image it won't change the article meaning, so that qualifies. But on the other hand, the thumbnail image isn't exactly self-contained.

[In another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19317918/651170) @unor suggested that only use figure if the image itself should have a separate caption. But in the spec we see that caption is optional.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for an opinion, as there's no single "correct" answer here, but rather different interpretations of the spec. Opinions are specifically off-topic, as mentioned in the [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: well, I don't know--wouldn't that be like saying semantic HTML is based on opinion? Is there no standards in writing semantic markup? I'm looking for this standards because semantic markup can get confusing.

Comment: Please take a look at [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272602/215552) regarding these kinds of questions.

Comment: Since the `html5` is a live spec what defines the semantics is community usage.  Therefore, i believe, it is a good question.  Whether community usage is an opinion it is debatable.  Moreover, stack overflow is the biggest community of programmers worldwide, therefore there is hardly a better place to ask a question as this one.

Answer (score 4):

Think of `<figure>` as something like a chart, or a callout image, or a table, or a code block, that you might see in a news article or tutorial.

If it warrants a caption of any kind, then use `<figure>` as it has a `figcaption` element to support that. Lack of caption does *not* mean that `<figure>` is not allowed, and `<figure>` does not require a `figcaption`. You can

Not all images belong in `<figure>`. For example, if it gets no `alt` text or other text description (`longdesc`, for example), then it probably does not qualify to use `<figure>` as its absence likely affects nothing.

If the image is simply there as eye candy, perhaps a lead-in image that is primarily decoration, then you can probably just skip using `<figure>`. Whether your choose to wrap it in a `<p>` or not (or whatever) is up to you.

Without seeing more context (images, a full page, etc), since you describe it as an index with *thumbnails* and their absence does not damage the meaning, I think you should ignore `<figure>`.

There is some relatively recent discussion on this 2010 article: http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/

Comment: Also note that according to WHATWG spec (also known as "HTML5"), the `<figure>` element should enclose "self-contained" information and it should be logically okay to move all the figure elements at the bottom of the content (e.g. to the end of surrounding `<article>` element) without changing the meaning of the content. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element