# Semantic element for article promos

Tags: html, semantics

I'm a little bit confused about what semantic html element I should use for article promos.

**Article promo examples**

- [article-promo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgkjz.png)
- [article-promo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMlZO.png)
- [article-promo3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcJYn.png)

I really can't decide between <article> and <section>.

Couldn't find info about this topic on the web, but if there is - feel free to just drop the link.

Comment: I would say there's a ton of information about this topic. Search for "article-promo" or "article-teaser" and you''ll fin a lot of information. Another  tip is to have a look at how newspaper sites structures their promos? Read about [<article>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)

Comment: Thanks a lot, "article-teaser" search helps.

Comment: I found a great answer about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307443/semantic-html-of-an-articles-list).

Answer (score 0):

it is all about you ..you can put section inside an article, or put an article inside a section...
what is the article?
The HTML article element represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site, which is intended to be independently distributable or reusable (e.g., in syndication).

what is the section?
The HTML section element represents a standalone section — which doesn't have a more specific semantic element to represent it — contained within an HTML document. Typically, but not always, **sections have a heading**.
 in your case, I think you can use section